# Using conditional formatting to shade alternating groups of cells of variable size

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am facing an issue where I need to shade a row of cells either blue or orange based on if the user has check-marked the "swap" cell.
Essentially, the rows will start blue and continue to be blue.
When the user presses the checkmark in the Swap column, all rows after that point will now be orange.
Once again, if the user presses the checkmark in the Swap column (below the above checkmarks), the rows will go back to being blue from that point on.
This will alternate forever, as demonstrated in this image.

[image]

I am using some conditional formatting code that uses a "helper" column that is hidden. If the value is 1, then the row is coloured orange. If the value is 0, it is coloured blue. The problem is I don't know how to "search" for groups of checkmarks. Each checkmark will only colour the individual row it is in.

The helper column has this code: `=MOD(IF(ROW()=2,0,IF(D25=D24,E24, E24+1)), 2)`
The D column is where the checkmarks are, and begins at D24.
The E column is my helper column and begins at E24.

I can scrap this whole setup if someone can guide me into how to set this up.
I need it to essentially "change" the values of every row below a checkmark, until it finds another checkmark, and do the reverse so that the colouring can properly format.

Comment: Just a quick clarification, the formula for the helper column was taken using this tutorial: https://www.redargyle.com/blog/alternate-row-color-based-value-change-google-sheets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `0:00` is in A1, please select ColumnsA:C and: (i) fill all with 'standard' fill blue and (ii) Format > Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... *Custom formula is* and:

```
=isodd(COUNTIF($C$1:$C1,TRUE))
```

with brown highlighting.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm.